# pandas object indexes can be either string or int, how can I tell them apart?

Tags: python, pandas, types

I've got 2 pandas dataframes, each of them has an index with dtype `object`, and in both of them I can see the value `533`. However, when I join them the result is empty, as one of them is the number `533` and the other is a string `"533"`.

I've found out a really cumbersome way to know in advance that won't match. I try `df.loc["533"]` and `df.loc[533]` and wait to see which one will fail...

There must be a better way, right?

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the dataframes first and converting them explicitly? (I'm assuming they're all numbers)

Comment: You can force them all to be one or the other using int or str.

Comment: Do you want to make them to match (by casting to a common type), or do you just want to check their types to *know* they won't match?

Comment: @ajcr - I prefer to know that they won't match before I cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to tell them apart is to use the "is_type" methods that Index objects are equipped with. This lets you infer the type of values the index holds and therefore whether joining/reindexing will give you the results that you expect.

An alternative way might be to check the `dtype` of the index directly, but this would give you *false-negative* results when comparing, say, an int-type index with an object-type index which held only integers.

Here's an example with four Index objects to highlight the "is_type" methods:

```
idx1 = pd.Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])             # int64 dtype
idx2 = pd.Index(['0','1','2','3','4'])       # object dtype, strings
idx3 = pd.Index([0,'1',2,'3',4])             # object dtype, ints and strings
idx4 = pd.Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='O')  # object dtype, holds ints
```

Your question chiefly concerns checking whether an index holds strings or integers. In this case you can use `is_integer()`:

```
>>> idx1.is_integer()
True
>>> idx2.is_integer()
False
```

Because `idx2` contains at least one string, the check returns `False`. So you know that joining/reindexing an integer index like `idx1` won't work.

However, the same check will return `True` for an object dtype index holding *only* integers (and so joining/reindexing with `idx1` will succeed):

```
>>> idx4.is_integer()
True
```

Another useful check is `is_mixed()` which lets you check if an index (with object dtype) holds a mix of different types:

```
>>> idx3.is_mixed()
True
```

---

For reference, the available type-inference methods for all `Index` objects are:

```
is_all_dates
is_boolean
is_categorical
is_floating
is_integer
is_mixed
is_numeric
is_object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# String index
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]}, index = ["1", "2", "3"])

# Int index
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]}, index = [1, 2, 3])

# Convert string index to integers:
df1.index = df1.index.astype(int)

# Convert integer index to strings:
df2.index = df2.index.astype(str)
```